# "Invalid parameter: authy_id - Parameter is required". How can I pass authy_id to get authy_id?

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-api

I tried to implement twilio SMS verification in my app. I followed [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/twilio-verification-sdk-integration-guide) guide to implement SMS verification. Now I am getting sms successfully but it is not recognized by twilio API.
Do I need to add user in my app using REST or manually to get verified by twilio api?

I tried to follow [this](https://inika.herokuapp.com/) guide to add user like this to get my authy_id

```
{
"api_key":"OaQi0sSxw9UVbJr234vGj0MOgdfZFkn5",
"email":"jxyz198@gmail.com",
"cellphone":"7989661708",
"country_code":"91"
}
```

but it is asking for authy id as parameter with this response.

```
{
"error_code": "60004",
"message": "Invalid parameter: authy_id - Parameter is required",
"errors": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter: authy_id - Parameter is required"
},
"success": false
}
```

how can i provide authy_id while I am generatig one?

Answer (score 0):

Correct url for creating user is:
https://api.authy.com/protected/json/users/new

Working example:

```
curl -X POST --data "api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&\
user[email]=new_user@email.com&\
user[cellphone]=405-342-5699&\
user[country_code]=1" \
https://api.authy.com/protected/json/users/new
```

Response:

```
{"message":"User created successfully.","user":{"id":48952},"success":true}
```

Also

```
curl -X POST --data "api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&authy_id=48952"\
https://api.authy.com/protected/json/sdk/registrations
```

Returns response:

```
{"registration_token":"3D98vsvh4GcaZM4EVXt4RLQXvszM8NNo1lqftYv8czk","success":true}
```

and you can use this token for SDK